# .htacess rewrite rule not working for a specific string?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^healthcheck/?$ /README.txt [NC,L,R=307]
```

in my .htaccess. What's strange about it is that when I change the string `healthcheck` to any other string the rewrite rule works. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a "`healthcheck.php`" or "`healthcheck.html`" file in the same folder? Or a `healthcheck` folder?

Comment: no I get 404 not found.

Comment: Do you have a `/healthcheck/.htaccess` file also?

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I did have a healthcheck.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file called `healthcheck.php` and that is causing this rule to not get applied:

```
RewriteRule ^healthcheck/?$ /README.txt [NC,L,R=307]
```

It sounds like you need to turn off multiviews, which is part of mod_negotiation and supercedes whatever mod_rewrite rules you have. Mod_negotiation will see the request `/healthcheck` and then see that there's a file called `/healthcheck.php` and assumes that the request was really for the php file. Turning it off will end up having mod_rewrite handle it:

```
Options -Multiviews
```